# loop through array issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling an API that returns an array, i am trying to loop through the array but console is saying that the lenght is 0, never seen anything like it before and can not find out what is the issue here:

```
const funCall=async()=>{

      const userNFTsURLs = await prepareData();
      setNFTsUrls(userNFTsURLs);
}

  const prepareData = async () => {
    const res = await getUserNFTs();
    console.log(res);
/*returns 
0: "ipfs://QmbNHPexuZWo3rnzAyyzZxTsAmMuN97R8Z7qwuPfEMXeX9/4.json"
1: "ipfs://QmbNHPexuZWo3rnzAyyzZxTsAmMuN97R8Z7qwuPfEMXeX9/41.json"
2: "ipfs://QmbNHPexuZWo3rnzAyyzZxTsAmMuN97R8Z7qwuPfEMXeX9/45.json"
3: "ipfs://QmbNHPexuZWo3rnzAyyzZxTsAmMuN97R8Z7qwuPfEMXeX9/47.json"
4: "ipfs://QmbNHPexuZWo3rnzAyyzZxTsAmMuN97R8Z7qwuPfEMXeX9/49.json"
5: "ipfs://QmbNHPexuZWo3rnzAyyzZxTsAmMuN97R8Z7qwuPfEMXeX9/51.json"
length: 6
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)*/

    console.log(res.length);//returns 0


    res.map((rest: string) => console.log(rest));
    const test = res.map((url: string) => {
console.log(url)//does not return anything is not being called
      return url;
    });

    return res;
  };
```

getUserNFTs function, I just console logged the last forEach, it is loging it after it is logged on the component consuming it, it is very strange.

```
 const getUserNFTs = async () => {
    if (store.getState().blockChain.smartContract === null) {
      await connectToContract();
    }
    try {
      const balance = await getUserTokensBalance();
      if (balance <= 0) {
        return [];
      }
      let tokenIds = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < balance; i++) {
        const tokenId = await blockChain.smartContract.methods
          .tokenOfOwnerByIndex(walletId, i)
          .call();
        tokenIds.push(tokenId);
      }

      let tokensList: any = [];

      tokenIds.forEach(async (tokenId) => {
        const token = await blockChain.smartContract.methods
          .tokenURI(tokenId)
          .call();
        console.log("token", token);//logs it on console after logs al the other console logs

        tokensList.push(token);
      });

      return tokensList;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

what am I not getting here? I feel very frustrated after couple of hours trying to find out

Comment: What's in `getUserNFTs`?

Comment: is a call to a smart contract, basically returns the array with strings

Comment: Can you include the output of `JSON.toString(res)` in your post so we can see the exact structure of your array?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); returns [] empty array, that is very strange

Comment: I added the function below in the post, is console loging after all the console logs in the other. functions. which is strange for me

Comment: Could you try changing `tokenIds.forEach` to a regular for loop?

Comment: You have a problem with your asynchronity. The tokenIds being logged after the consumer are proof of that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you're using `forEach` which is not waiting for results as you expected.

You should modify it to a usual `for` loop to get rid of `async` callback function in `forEach`.

```
for(const tokenId of tokenIds) {
        const token = await blockChain.smartContract.methods
          .tokenURI(tokenId)
          .call();
        console.log("token", token);//logs it on console after logs al the other console logs

        tokensList.push(token);
};
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot!, i wasted half day trying to find a solution for this thing, did not see anywhere that for each does not wait for response but deffinetly good to know for the future, :)

Comment: You're welcome!~ Just one side note that, for all these kinds of callback functions, you need to be careful with `async/await`. They may never return results in callbacks @Jgarnie